# Evaluate:: $ 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\left( 1 + \frac12 +\cdots + \frac 1n\right) $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to evaluate the series:
$$  2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\left( 1 + \frac12 + \cdots + \frac 1n\right) $$

According to Mathematica, this converges to $ (\log 2)^2 $.

Comment: What is the summand when $n=0$?  Is it just $-1$?  Or perhaps the summation runs from $n=1$ to $n = \infty$ instead?

Comment: For large $n$ the absolute value of adjacent terms is $ n\log{(n+1)}/((n+1) \log{n}) \sim (n \log{n}+1)/(n \log{n} +n)$ which does go to zero.

Comment: For $|a_{n+1}|\leq |a_n|$, write the inequality down, multiply by $n+2$, then use $\frac{n+2}{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{n+1}$. It works.

Comment: For some reason, I could not fix my error.  The last term in the denominator should be $\log{n}$, not $n$.  The conclusion is the same.

Comment: @rlgordonma I ran `2 Sum[2 (-1)^(n + 1)/(n + 1) Sum[1/k, {k, 1, n}], {n, 0, Infinity}]` on mathematica

Comment: @julien no luck!! could you give a little more hint??

Comment: $\frac{n+2}{n+1}(1+\ldots+1/n)=(1+1/(n+1))(1+\ldots+1/n)=1+\ldots+1/n+ (1/(n+1))(1+\ldots+1/n)\geq 1+\ldots+1/n+1/(n+1)$.

Comment: @julien thank you very much!!

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, what is your answer to Antonio's comment above? There really is a problem of definition when $n=0$.

Comment: I don't think so, since it is the sum of Cauchy product of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}$. Still, I think we could shift it up and evaluate it from 1.

Comment: @julien the result is same when evaluating from $n=1$. The first case will be ignored since there is nothing at the harmonic part.

Comment: @experimentX you answered your own question... your sum is exactly equal to the product $$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)^2 = (-\log 2)^2 = (\log 2)^2.$$

Comment: @AntonioVargas huh!! could you elaborate it please?? I am not getting the picture.

Comment: Okay, I'll type it up.

Comment: Hint: If $f(x)=(\log x)^2$, then 
$f^{(n+1)}(1)=2\,(-1)^{n+1}(n!)(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n})$. See [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269000/n-th-derivative-of-frac-ln-xx/269013#269013)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Recall that, formally,

$$
\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n+1},$$

where

$$
c_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k b_{n-k}.
$$

If the series $\sum c_{n+1}$ converges, [then the above equality is actually true](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Ces.C3.A0ro.27s_theorem).  You seem to know how to show this, so I'll just demonstrate the formal aspect of the problem.

Let $a_n = b_n = \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$.  Then

$$
a_k b_{n-k} = \frac{(-1)^n}{k(n-k)} = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n-k}\right),
$$

so that

$$
\begin{align*}
c_n &= \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n-k}\right) \\
&= 2\frac{(-1)^n}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}.
\end{align*}
$$

We therefore have

$$
2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} = \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)^2 = (-\log 2)^2 = (\log 2)^2.
$$

Comment: wow!! i only knew one had to absolutely convergent.

Comment: @experimentX, You may be interested in [these notes](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/243series7.pdf) (the bottom of p.4), which proves that result using Abel's theorem.

Comment: For searching purposes: what Antonio has used here is the fact that the Cauchy product of the generating functions of two independent sequences is the generating function of the convolution of the two sequences. (+1, of course.)

Comment: For an updated reference, see Theorem 14.17 in Pete L. Clark's [Honors Calculus notes](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/expositions2012.html).

Answer (score 20):

Use generating functions:

Consider
$$-\log(1-x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}.$$
Dividing by $1-x$, we get
$$-\frac{\log(1-x)}{1-x} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\right)x^n.$$
Integrating this and multiplying everything by $2$ gives
$$\left[\log(1-x)\right]^2 = 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\right)\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + C,$$
where $C$ is some constant. But we can get rid of $C$ by plugging $x=0$ into both sides, which gives $C=0$:
$$\left[\log(1-x)\right]^2 = 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\right)\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}.$$
From here, we'd like to simply plug in $x=-1$ and say our answer is $(\log{2})^2$, but we have to first check to make sure the power series on the right actually *converges* there. To do this, set $H_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots + \frac{1}{n}$ (the "$H$" is for "harmonic", since $H_n$ is the $n$th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)). Let's see when the inequality
$$ \frac{(n+1)H_{n+1}}{(n+2)H_n}<1$$
holds. Rearranging terms, and using the fact that $H_{n+1}=H_n+\frac{1}{n+1}$, it follows that the above inequality holds exactly when $H_n>1$. But a quick glance at the definition of $H_n$ shows that this is *always* true! Therefore, the terms of our series decrease in absolute value. Since they also converge to zero (they're all less than $1/(n+1)$, which converges to zero), the entire series converges by the alternating series test.

Comment: wow!! this is also very nice!!

Comment: You are implicitly using Abel's theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem

Comment: Nice answer, easy way to follow! (+1)

Comment: The line with the 1st inequality sign in this answer is **wrong**.We are reducing the numerator by 1 so the RHS should be lesser than the LHS.

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife I'm surprised I got 13 upvotes before anyone noticed that! I've (hopefully) fixed it, and in the process actually ended up in my opinion simplifying the convergence argument. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 16):

This is a special case of a more general result derived [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275643/proving-an-alternating-euler-sum-sum-k-1-infty-frac-1k1-h-kk/275657#275657).

$$S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1} \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1k$$
Recall that $\dfrac1k = \displaystyle \int_0^1 x^{k-1} dx$ and $\dfrac1{n+1} = \displaystyle \int_0^1 y^n dy$.

Now use the following fact.
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_0^1 (-z)^k dz = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \dfrac{1 - (-z)^n}{1+z} dz$$
The sequence of  functions $f_n(z) = \dfrac{1 - (-z)^n}{1+z}$ is dominated by the function $g(z) = \dfrac2{1+z}$ in the interval $[0,1]$, which is integrable. Hence, we can swap the limit and the integral to get that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \dfrac{1 - (-z)^n}{1+z} dz = \int_0^1 \dfrac{dz}{1+z}$$

Hence,
$$S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \int_0^1 y^n dy \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \int_0^1 x^{k-1} dx  \right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \int_0^1 y^n dy \left(\int_0^1 \dfrac{1-x^n}{1-x} dx  \right)$$
Hence,
$$S = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \dfrac{\dfrac{y}{1+y} - \dfrac{xy}{1+xy}}{1-x} dy dx = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \dfrac{y+xy^2-xy-xy^2}{(1+y)(1+xy)(1-x)} dx dy\\
=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \dfrac{y}{(1+y)(1+xy)} dx dy = \int_0^1 \dfrac{\log(1+y)}{1+y} dy = \left. \dfrac{\log^2(1+y)}2 \right \vert_0^1 = \dfrac{\log^2(2)}2$$
The sum you are interested in is $2S$ and hence the answer is $\log^2(2)$.

Comment: Beautiful answer, but how do you justify swapping the infinite sum and integrals?

Comment: @PeterM I have clarified this by updating the answer. Let me know if I have missed something out.

Comment: sweet indeed - there's a small typo $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_0^1 (-z)^k dy$ should be $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_0^1 (-z)^k dz$

Comment: @nikola Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: @Marvis Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/499689), it is shown that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}H_n=\frac12\zeta(2)-\frac12\log(2)^2
$$
This sum is
$$
\begin{align}
2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}H_{n-1}
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\left(\frac1n-H_n\right)\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}H_n\\
&=\zeta(2)-\left(\zeta(2)-\log(2)^2\right)\\[6pt]
&=\log(2)^2
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach that I just noticed
$$
\begin{align}
2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k
&=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{k(n+1)}\tag{1}\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{k(n+k)}\tag{2}\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+k}\frac1n\left(\frac1k-\frac1{n+k}\right)\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+k}\frac1n\frac1k\tag{4}\\[6pt]
&=\log(2)^2\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: change the order of summation
$(2)$: substitute $n\mapsto n+k-1$
$(3)$: partial fractions
$(4)$: swap $n$ and $k$ in $(2)$ add to $(3)$ and divide by $2$
$(5)$: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}=\log(2)$

Comment: Beautiful, step (4) is amazing

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n + 1} \over n + 1}
\pars{1 + {1 \over 2} + \cdots + {1 \over n}} =
-2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\, H_{n}\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\,\dd x =
-2\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}H_{n}\pars{-x}^{n}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-2\int_{0}^{1}\braces{-\,{\ln\pars{1 - \bracks{-x}} \over 1 - \pars{-x}}}\,\dd x =
2\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 +x} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x =
\left.\ln^{2}\pars{1 + x}\,\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ 0}^{\ x\ =\ 1} =
\bbx{\ds{\ln^{2}\pars{2}}}
\end{align}